# Open file with WordPad in Java

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I want to open a file in [WordPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPad). I've tried the following:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().edit(fileName);
```

But the file opens with [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29). How can I force WordPad to open the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Desktop.getDesktop().edit(fileName);` opens Notepad by default. To achieve what you want, you need to use `ProcessBuilder`:

**NOTE:** *This code works on my computer with Windows 7. You must use the path to your `wordpad.exe` to make it work, as well as adjust `fileName` accordingly.*

```
// get filename
String fileName = "C:\\tmp\\Q37545784.txt";

// get executable of wordpad
String wordPadExecutable = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows NT\\Accessories\\wordpad.exe";

// create a process builder that executes wordpad and passes filename as parameter
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(wordPadExecutable, fileName);

// start
pb.start();
```

Comment: Did you try it without using the full path? [How is it possible to run Wordpad by just typing its name even though it isn’t on the PATH?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110725-00/?p=10073/) That works through the .NET framework, but I don't have Java to test with.